# Unable to run apache-beam pipeline using KafkaIO on Dataflow

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to consume kafka message using apache beam in dataflow. I write a simple pipeline using apache beam version 2.1.0 below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrainOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(DrainOptions.class);
    options.setStreaming(true);

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    props.put("group.id", "test-group");

    p.apply(KafkaIO.readBytes()
            .updateConsumerProperties(props)
            .withTopic(options.getTopic())
            .withBootstrapServers(options.getBootstrapServer())
    ).apply(ParDo.of(new GetValue()))
            .apply("ToString", ParDo.of(new ToString()))
            .apply("FixedWindow", Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30))))
            .apply(TextIO.write().to(options.getOutput()).withWindowedWrites().withNumShards(1));

    PipelineResult pipelineResult = p.run();
    pipelineResult.waitUntilFinish();
}
```

When it tried to run it using dataflow runner :

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.test.beamexample.Drain -Dexec.args="--project=my-project --gcpTempLocation=gs://my_bucket/tmp/drain --streaming=true --stagingLocation=gs://my_bucket/staging/drain --output=gs://my_bucket/output/staging/drainresult --bootstrapServer=kafka-broker:9092 --topic=test --runner=DataflowRunner" -Pdataflow-runner
```

The pipeline successfully being built and being uploaded to staging location, but before Dataflow runner run the pipeline, it being executed in local, that makes no Dataflow job created, like when we are using direct-runner :

```
Nov 14, 2017 2:14:52 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 111 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Nov 14, 2017 2:14:53 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner run
INFO: Executing pipeline on the Dataflow Service, which will have billing implications related to Google Compute Engine usage and other Google Cloud Services.
Nov 14, 2017 2:14:53 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFO: Uploading 111 files from PipelineOptions.filesToStage to staging location to prepare for execution.
Nov 14, 2017 2:14:59 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil stageClasspathElements
INFO: Staging files complete: 111 files cached, 0 files newly uploaded
Nov 14, 2017 2:15:00 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator addStep
INFO: Adding KafkaIO.Read/Read(UnboundedKafkaSource)/DataflowRunner.StreamingUnboundedRead.ReadWithIds as step s1
Nov 14, 2017 2:15:00 PM org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig logAll
INFO: ConsumerConfig values: 
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
...
```

Are there something missing ?

Comment: From the logs it seems after DataflowPipelineTranslator added KafkaIO.Read step, the KafkaConsumer is created and running immediately. That makes translation pipeline object to Dataflow Service API jobs is stopped midway, before adding another pipeline step and started it in Dataflow runner.

Comment: Are you wondering why KafkaConsumer is created locally? That is expected. This is normal part of initialization of a pipeline before runner launches the job on Dataflow. During initialization KafkaIO needs to contact Kafka cluster to figure out number of partitions for a topic.
Is it stuck? One issue could be that your local machine can't access remote Kafka cluster (but if you were able to run in DirectRunner, then it should be ok).

Comment: yes, i see, yeah it was stuck .

being told that it was the kafka clients version in my project, i was forgot to include the kafka clients dependency. the kafka io dependency is not enough. thats why it was stuck.

Comment: I see. KafkaIO until Beam 2.2.0 depends on fairly older version of kafka-clients version (0.9) in order accommodate all the versions. Often you need to specify higher version of the client in your dependencies that is compatible with your cluster. It works with all the versions since Kafka 0.9.x.
I think it is better for KafkaIO to move its kakfka-client dependency to maven provided scope so that users always specify a version to include at runtime.